# How to load ODBC in qt

Tags: database, qt, odbc, qtsql

I'm very new to `Qt` and `C++`

I'm trying to connect to an ODBC db, but I'm getting the following output

```
QSqlDatabase: QODBC driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE
```

How do I load `ODBC` in `Qt`.

CODE :

```
QString serverName = "LOCALHOST\\SQLEXPRESS";
QString dbName = "test";

QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");

db.setConnectionOptions();

QString myCon = QString("DRIVER={SQL Native Client};SERVER=%1;DATABASE=%2;Trusted_Connection = Yes").arg(serverName).arg(dbName);

db.setDatabaseName(myCon);

if(db.open())
{
   qDebug() << "Opened!";
   db.close();
}
else
{
   qDebug() << "Error : " << db.lastError().text();
}
```

I tried to follow the steps online, but it's very confusing.

Can someone give me a simplified approach to doing this?

Comment: How did you call `QSqlDatabase::addDatabase()`?

Comment: Hey @Mat, I've added my code..

Answer (score 1):

You will have to manually build the ODBC plugin if you haven't done so already.

[This link](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/sql-driver.html#how-to-build-the-odbc-plugin-on-windows) describes how to build it (Assuming you're on Windows. If not, scroll up a bit.)

In case you already built it or this step didn't work, create a directory in your project called "sqldrivers" and copy the qsqlodbc.dll from the Qt directory into it.