# How to upload video files to a remote MySQL server using Qt creator

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, video

I'm new to Qt and am fairly new to C++ but I'm a very fast learner and have been able to build a prototype application with Qt creator and I intend to take it to the next level.

Basically, the application is a GUI that allows a user to capture or record videos. The user have the option to upload the video while recording (real time) to a remote MySQL server or to save the video in local storage and upload it later.

I'm displaying the saved recordings with a QListView. The user selects the video he wants to upload from the list. When the user selects a video to upload, the list emits a signal that returns the location of the video. This is where am stuck.

I want to be able to upload the selected video to a server (a MySQL server to be precise). I don't know how to go about this. I tried to read documentation on Qt networking (especially QNetworkAccessManager) could not get a hold on how to do this. I know it's fairly difficult but as I said, am a very fast learner, with a few example I can accomplish great stuff.

Please I need a resource I can go through or a simple example I can use as an compass. I apologize that I might not know a few things but trust me, I can learn immediately. I promise to post my success story. Note that I've actually google(d) a lot before turning to the StackOverFlow family for help because I know I'll get some here. Thank you very much in advance.

**NB: Am coming from a Java background therefore adapting to C++ or Qt Networking should not be a problem**

Comment: You can't find any examples because its a bad idea. Storing large binary objects with sql will not scale. it would be way better to use an HTTP put/post

Comment: Thank you @szatmary Please can you point me to an example as you have suggested?

Answer (score 0):

Using Qt networking features is indeed not the right way to go. What you want to do is use some plug-in dedicated to communication with databases through some driver (typically, for SQL Server, that would be an *ODBC* driver).

Have a look at the links below for further details:

- [SQL Database Drivers](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/sql-driver.html) from Qt documentation
- [How to load ODBC in qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142657/how-to-load-odbc-in-qt) on Stack Overflow